# Working locally with local branches hanging in pull-request remotely

Tags: git, github

I have a remote repo and a local copy. Let's imagine I have worked on 2 features in different local branches:

- `feature1`
- `feature2`

For now I've finished them and pushed them into a remote repo for pull-requests. Now I need to implement a `feature3` which depends on `feature1` and `feature2`.

What is the right way to continue it on local machine? For example, I don't want to have some side-effect in case my pull-requests of `feature1` or `feature2` will be canceled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which depends on feature1 and feature2.
>   What is the right way to continue it on local machine?

You don't have much choice (to go on working locally): you merge f1 and f2, and create f3 from there.

> I dont want to have some side-effect in case my pull-requests of feature1 or feature2 will be canceled.

Assuming f1 or f2 is accepted, you will:

- fetch from upstream (the original repo you have forked)
- rebase f3 commits on top of upstream/master (which will include f1 or f2)

  ```
  git rebase --onto upstream/master $(git merge-base f1 f3) f3
  ```
- add the minimum amount of code from the missing feature for f3 to work again.